# creating a very specificly order text file with ls

Tags: python, shell, find, ls

I have a python script that reads in input files from a text file. Ideally the text file should have one line per directory and that line should have all the files in that directory separated by a comma and with the full path, so something like this:
Line 1: Directory1/fileA,Directory1/fileB
Line 2: Directory2/fileC,Directory2/fileD,Directory2/fileE
I have been using sublime text to do this but my collaborators don't use sublime text so they want a command to make this text files. I've been trying with ls -m but I get just one line with all the directories and all the files. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

with bash: iterate over the directories, store the filenames in an array and then print out the array elements joined with a comma

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob
for d in */; do
    files=("$d"*)
    ((${#files[*]} > 0)) && (IFS=,; echo "${files[*]}")
done
```

I assume you don't want to see directories that have no files.